# LIst out the custom packages from all users in database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I need the procedure for want custom packages from all users in database, I am giving step by step explanation and I need the query or some clues for how to display and select specific user.

1.List out the database **users** which already in database.

2.We have to select one specific user example **Ranjith** by input method.

3.After selecting the users should display the custom packages of selected users.

4.Next step is it should display the source code of all custom packages which you already selected users.

**1.SELECT USERNAME FROM DBA_USERS** (*it will display all the users from database, After that I need to select specific users to display custom packages*)

Thank you.

Comment: First off, the requirement is not clear. Where are you trying to display your data, in a swing application, in a console? How are you trying to access the database? What is the database structure? This is not specific enough and you need to show what you have tried, no one is going to write you an entire solution.

Comment: Actually this is my assignment so i need to display the users only in local machine so that i given theoretically

Comment: if u want to display the users from db mean we will use SELECT USERNAME FROM DBA_USERS _at the same like this after displayed like 10 users how can i select specific user and display the custom packages_

Comment: Totally i need output like below: 1. All the usernames of DB 2.It should prompt me for anyone user for which i want detail 3.For specific user selected display all packages 4.display source code for specific package All these statements i need it in one PL/SQL program.Thanks in advance for solutn

Answer (score 0):

```
select object_name from dba_OBJECTs where owner = '{schema}' and  object_type in ('FUNCTION','PACKAGE','PROCEDURE'); -- get user function,pkg, procedure. 

select * from dba_source where owner = '{schema}' and name = '{object_name}' order by type,line asc; -- view source of objects.
```

If you want extract ddl of object, you use dbms_metadata.

```
select name,text from dba_source where owner = '{user}' and type in ('PACKAGE' ,'PACKAGE BODY','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE') 
order by name,type,line asc; -- return all source code for specifed user
```

Comment: I need more from you Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz. My requirement is to display all users then it should prompt for anyone user among all user selected.Then for particular user to display all packages.once the packages listed under that user we need source code for all packages.

Comment: but what's your question

Comment: Totally i need output like below:

Comment: First query return list of all package, function and procedure for specifed user. 
Secound query can return source code line by line for specifed user and object_name(e.g package name).

Comment: Totally i need output like below:                                                                  1. All the usernames of DB                                                                                2.It should prompt me for anyone user for which i want detail                        3.For specific user selected display all packages                                            4.display source code for specific package                                                       All these statements i need it in one PL/SQL program.Thanks in advance for solutn

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz please get me some idea to execute those in pl/sql. I can do it sql